# "Error: unable to verify the first certificate" [Heroku]

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-cli

[image]

Can someone help me out with this error. I am trying to login to my heroku account with heroku toolbelt but i keep getting this error.Any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

Try running 'heroku update' in terminal

once it is updated then try login in to your heroku account

Comment: it throws the same error saying "Error: unable to verify the first certificate" !

Answer (score 0):

In my case, an adblocking application filtered all my traffic. Even that of the console. To do this, it injects a certificate that the `heroku` app cannot verify. This is the right approach to prevent API traffic sniffing.

Once I prevented the filtering, everything worked fine again.

Answer (score -1):

fix this is simply use the fullkey.pem when heroku asks for a cert

Comment: But it does not ask for any cert ?! it just throws this error after entering the password

Comment: Try this [sudo] gem install certified

add to gemfile : gem 'certified'

bundle install